# Create horizontal spacing between buttons with more than one word?

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4EtB.jpg

I have a navbar and I'm trying to create horizontal space between "About Harvard" and "Admission and Aid". I've tried word-spacing but that creates space around every single word, which is not the intended effect.

Here's my CSS.

```
    position: fixed; 
    top: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 10px;
    top: 40px;
    
    
    
    
    
}
.nav2 li { 
    display:inline;

    
    
    
}

.nav3 { position: fixed; 
    top: 50px; 
    width: 50%;
    left: 50vw;
    border: 5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 10px;
    top: 40px;
    
    

}

.nav3 li { 
    display: inline; 
    

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Plz, include the HTML also.  And add proper CSS with all selectors.

Comment: There also seems to be an issue with vertical space...

Answer (score 0):

margin should do the trick for you

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

heres a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uwy6g9?file=style.css